# How to configure Discourse with External DB connection?

Tags: discourse

I need to configure discourse with an external db instance connectivity(PostgreSQL). Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

If your are using the official launcher installation then to use external DB you have to follow the below provided procedures

You have to build the app with different template

If you are planning to use docker for db

1. Copy data.yml from samples to containers folder.
2. Edit the data.yml to update the password and container path
3. Build the db container by the command ./laucher bootstrap data

To start web only container

1. Copy the web_only.yml from sample to containers folder and modify the db and other parameters
2. Build the web container by running ./launcher bootstrap web_only

This will launch the app and db container separately.